# Save a row to csv format

Tags: perl, csv

I have a set of rows from a DB that I would like to save to a csv file.
Taking into account that the data are ascii chars without any weird chars would the following suffice?

```
my $csv_row = join( ', ', @$row );  
# save csv_row to file
```

My concern is if that would create rows that would be acceptable as CSV by any tool and e.g not be concern with quoting etc.

**Update:**
Is there any difference with this?

```
my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1, eol    => "\n"} );
my $header = join (',', qw( COL_NAME1 COL_NAME2 COL_NAME3 COL_NAME4 ) );
$csv->print( $fh, [$header] );                                                                             
foreach my $row ( @data ) {  
  $csv->print($fh,  $row );    
}
```

This gives me as a first line:

```
" COL_NAME1,COL_NAME2,COL_NAME3,COL_NAME4"
```

Please notice the double quotes and the rest of the rows are without any quotes.
What is the difference than my plain `join`?  Also do I need the `binary` set?

Comment: @zdim: Yes actually I was wondering why I should use a module if this approach works. May be I should be having quotes or something that I am deglecting in order to make sure it is acceptable as CSV by any program

Comment: @zdim: You mean use JSON instead of CSV? I didn't understand the suggestion about `JSON_XS`

Comment: Ugh, very sorry ... drifted from another comment. It's [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/Text-CSV-1.95/lib/Text/CSV.pm).  I am removing that comment. This is precisely one thing where a solid module helps (I think that your format is fine but am unsure).

Comment: At the very least, you have an extra space at the beginning of each column by the first. Also, how can you be sure there won't ever be any characters such as " or a newline or a comma? Using an existing module is probably a better option. Note also that CSV is probably the least standard standard: not all apps agree on its format, including field separator, line separator, encoding, escaping... if at all possible, pick another format.

Comment: @jcaron: Like what? JSON is a pain to be used e.g. in Google Sheets or Excel.

Comment: Some form of Excel format is probably a better option in terms of compatibility. Excel::Writer::XLSX is an option for this.

Comment: @zdim:Please see update in post

Comment: @jcaron: Please see update in post

Comment: @Jim  Thank you.  Posted an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way should be to write clean records with a comma separator. The simpler the better, specially with the format that has so much variation in real life. If *needed*, double quote each field.

The true strength in using the module is for reading of "real-life" data. But it makes perfect sense to use it for writing as well, for a uniform approach to CSV.  Also, options can then be set in a clear way, and the module can iron out some glitches in data.

The [Text::CSV](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/Text-CSV-1.95/lib/Text/CSV.pm) documentation tells us about `binary` option

> **Important Note:** The default behavior is to accept only ASCII characters in the range from `0x20` (space) to `0x7E` (tilde). This means that the fields can not contain newlines. If your data contains newlines embedded in fields, or characters above `0x7E` (tilde), or binary data, you ***must*** set `binary => 1` in the call to `new`. To cover the widest range of parsing options, you will always want to set binary.

I'd say use it.  Since you write a file this may be it for options, along with `eol` (or use `say` method). But do scan the many useful options and review their [defaults](http://search.cpan.org/~ishigaki/Text-CSV-1.95/lib/Text/CSV.pm#accessors).

As for your header, the `print` method expects an array reference where each field is an element, not a single string with comma-separated fields. So it is wrong to say

```
my $header = join (',', qw(COL_NAME1 COL_NAME2 COL_NAME3 COL_NAME4));  # WRONG
$csv->print( $fh, [$header] );
```

since the `$header` is a single string which is then made the sole element of the (anonymous) array reference created by `[ ... ]`. So it prints this string as the first field in the row, and since it detects in it the separator `,` itself it also double-quotes. Instead, you should have

```
$csv->print($fh, [COL_NAME1 COL_NAME2 COL_NAME3 COL_NAME4]);
```

or better assign column names to `@header` and then do `$csv->print($fh, \@header)`.

This is also an example of why it is good to use the module for writing – if a comma slips into an element of the array, supposed to be a single field, it is handled correctly by double-quoting.

---

A complete example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV_XS;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } ) 
    or die "Cannot use CSV: " . Text::CSV->error_diag();

my $file = 'output.csv';
open my $fh_out , '>', 'output.csv' or die "Can't open $file for writing: $!";

my @headers = qw( COL_NAME1 COL_NAME2 COL_NAME3 COL_NAME4 );
my @data = 1..4;

$csv->print($fh_out, \@headers);
$csv->print($fh_out, \@data);

close $fh_out;
```

what produces the file `output.csv`

```
COL_NAME1,COL_NAME2,COL_NAME3,COL_NAME4
1,2,3,4
```