# Write to new CSV file

Tags: perl, file, csv, text

I am trying to write data to a new CSV file. I know how to create the new file and how to gather the data I want from the old file, but I'm not sure how to actually write the gathered data to the new file. I want the columns that I print to also be written to the new CSV file. This is what I have so far:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV_XS;

my @data;
my $file = 'FinalTest.csv'; #original file
my $newfile = 'filteredData.csv'; #new file

my $csv = Text::CSV_XS->new({ binary => 1 });
open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Could not open $file: $!";

my $header = $csv->getline($fh)
   or die("No header\n");
$csv->column_names(@$header); #removes header row

while( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
    push @data, $row;
    printf "$row->[0]\t";
    printf "$row->[1]\t";
    printf "$row->[2]\t";
    printf "$row->[3]\t";
    printf "$row->[13]\n";
}

open my $newfile, '>', $newfile or die "Could not write $newfile"; #create new file
```

Comment: Why not just do : `./script.pl > new_file.csv` ?

Comment: A complete simple example for writing CSV in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45641994/4653379)

Answer (score -1):

You're very close, you've just got things in the wrong order. The line to `open` the new file should go before the `while` loop. And then you need to add that filehandle to the `printf` statements. Although really they should be just `print` statements as you're not doing any formatting.

```
open my $newfile, '>', $newfile or die "Could not write $newfile"; #create new file

while( my $row = $csv->getline($fh) ) {
    push @data, $row;
    print $newfile "$row->[0]\t";
    print $newfile "$row->[1]\t";
    print $newfile "$row->[2]\t";
    print $newfile "$row->[3]\t";
    print $newfile "$row->[13]\n";
}
```

Also, you could also do the line that does the output like this as it'll make it much easier if you want to change what columns you're outputting or re-order them.

```
print $newfile join("\t",@$row[0,1,2,3,13]),"\n";
```

And if you need the header in the output put this before the loop.

```
print $newfile join("\t",@$header[0,1,2,3,13]),"\n";
```